# Correct way to work with a many-to-many relationship in Amplify. Unable to make mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify

I have modelled a many-to-many relationship in Amplify between Product and Order. However, I cannot pass a productID when creating an Order. I get the error :

> The variables input contains a field name 'products' that is not defined for input object type 'CreateOrderInput'

### Product Model

```
type Product @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  price: Int
  Orders: [Order] @manyToMany(relationName: "ProductOrder")
}
```

### Order Model

```
type Order @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  totalprice: Int
  products: [Product] @manyToMany(relationName: "ProductOrder")
}
```

As per documentation, amplify creates a join table "ProductOrder" in dynamodb.

### createProduct according to Amplify

Amplify tells me that I can create a product with:

```
const newProduct = await API.graphql({
    query: createProduct,
    variables: {
        input: {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "price": 1020,
        "Orders": [],
    }
    }
});
```

As I don't have any orders yet, I create a product without linking it to an order. All working fine.

### createOrder according to Amplify

```
const newOrder = await API.graphql({
    query: createOrder,
    variables: {
        input: {
        "totalprice": 1020,
        "products": [],
    }
    }
});
```

When I want to create an order (and already have a product), I'm getting an error message.

> The variables input contains a field name 'products' that is not defined for input object type 'CreateOrderInput'

I analyze 'CreateOrderInput' and indeed it looks like this:

```
input CreateOrderInput {
    id: ID
    totalprice: Int!
}
```

So, basically what is the correct way of creating a new Order and passing a productID with it? Do I have to create the Order and then manually call createProductOrder and manually create a record in the join table (ProductOrder) ?